# How to access REST endpoint after getting tokens from InitiateAuth API of AWS cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a REST endpoint (a POC). I added AWS Cognito without API Gateway to that ec2 instance just to get authentication.

So far, I have used InitiateAuth API to get tokens for the user.
But, how can I access that endpoint by using those tokens?